# Suppose that $A\preceq B$. Prove that $A^C \preceq B^C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I´m really struggling with this exercise, and I think it´s because there really is only one difficult step in solving the problem, and that is defining a function $f: A^C \to B^C$ that is one-one. As C is of unknown cardinality, isn´t the only thing known about the functions in the sets $A^C$ and $B^C$ that if there is at least one one-one function in $A^C$ then there must be at least one in $B^C$, and that of there is at least one onto function in $B^C$ there must be at least one in $A^C$?

Any ideas on how to think about this?

Comment: What does $A\preceq B$ mean?

Comment: That A is less than or equinumerous with B i.e. there is at least one injection from A to B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Solve first for the case where $A\subseteq B$. Next reduce the general case back to that one by composing with an appropriate injection from $A$ into $B$.

Comment: Ok, so if $A \subseteq B$ then $A^C \subseteq B^C$ wich means that one injection $A^C \to B^C$ is the identity function. 
By then applying the known injection $h : A \to B$ the general case can be shown. I´m I on the right track here?

Comment: Well, that depends on what do you mean by "applying" the injection.

Comment: If $g \in A^C$ and $i \in B^C$, I´m thinking something like $g = h(i)$ when trying to find a rule for f, but does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by $h(i)$? The function $h$ takes elements from $a$ and $i$ is a function from $C$ to $B$.

Comment: I´m trying to define f as when taking a c∈C and applying g and then h, h(g(c)) = b, b∈B, the b obtained should equal the b from i(c).

Comment: Yes, and are you familiar with the definition of a composition of functions?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Given an injective function $h\colon A\to B$, what would be a *straightforward*  way to obtain an element $B^C$ (i.e. a map $C\to B$) from an arbitrary element of $A^C$ (i.e. a map $C\to A$)?